# What is this Peacock-like creature?

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

[image]

In the below picture I believe  bird in the foreground is a female. The one that opens the wings is the male.
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us some more details. How big is this animal? Where did you see it? What sort of habitat? Most importantly, what makes you think that isn't a peacock?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like male Great Argus (*[Argusianus argus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_argus)*) displaying to a female. The circular markings on the male pheasant's secondaries are pretty distinct. The specific epithet *argus* refers to a hundred-eyed giant from Greek mythology.

[image]

Comment: I think you're right, the answer could be improved with a [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=Great+Argus&rlz=1C1NHXL_enGB711GB711&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0_t3DydrgAhUS1-AKHZMBC_IQ_AUIDigB&biw=1280&bih=616#imgrc=Q77EANXpO75o6M:) of some sort & a note to the effect it's a species of [pheasant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_argus) wouldn't hurt either :)